# curl_multi_exec kills whole process when there ia a single timeout

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl_multi to send out emails out in a rolling curl script similar to this one but i added a curlopt_timeout of 10 seconds and a curlopt_connecttimeout of 20 seconds
http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

while testing it i reduced the timeouts to 1ms by using timeout_ms and connecttimeout_ms respectively, just to see how it handles a timeout. But the timeout kills the entire curl process. Is there a way to continue with the other threads even if one times out??
Thanks.

-devo

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

```
<?php
class Possibilities extends Thread {
    public function __construct($url){
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function run(){
        /*
        * Or use curl, this is quicker to make an example ...
        */
        return file_get_contents($this->url);
    }
}
$threads = array();
$urls = get_my_urls_from_somewhere();
foreach($urls as $index => $url){
    $threads[$index]=new Possibilities($url);
    $threads[$index]->start();
}
foreach($threads as $index => $thread ){
    if( ( $response = $threads[$index]->join() ) ){
        /** good, got a response */
    } else { /** we do not care **/ }
}
?>
```

My guess is, you are using curl multi as it's the only option for concurrent execution of the code sending out emails ... if this is the case, I do not suggest that you use anything like the code above, I suggest that you thread the calls to mail() directly as this will be faster and more efficient by far.

But now you know, you can thread in PHP .. enjoy :)